# Problem using boost::multi_index with composite key member functions

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap, boost-multi-index

I have the following container:

```cpp
using KeyValue = mutable_pair<Key, Value>;
using MyContainer = boost::multi_index_container<
    KeyValue,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<KeyValueTag>,
            boost::multi_index::composite_key<
                KeyValue,
                boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<KeyValue::first_type, unsigned int, &KeyValue::first_type::foo>,
                boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<KeyValue::first_type, unsigned int, &KeyValue::first_type::bar>,
                boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<KeyValue::first_type, unsigned int, &KeyValue::first_type::baz>,
            >
        >,
        boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<BazTag>,
            boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<KeyValue::first_type, unsigned int, &KeyValue::first_type::baz>
        >,
        boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<BarTag>,
            boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<KeyValue::first_type, unsigned int, &KeyValue::first_type::bar>
        >
    >
>;
```

Where `mutable_pair` is the [boost provided example for maps](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html), and `Key` is a class that contains `const` member accessors for `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

The code compiles fine, however when trying to query by any index ie:

```cpp
MyContainer c;
const auto& byBaz = c.get<BazTag>();
const auto it = byBaz.find(11);
// or
const auto [beg, end] = byBaz.equal_range(11);
```

it complains of

```
<long instantiation template error>
in mem_fun.hpp:58:23: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const mutable_pair<Key, Value>’)
   58 |     return operator()(*x);
```

What am I missing? I've been struggling with this for hours :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code compiles fine

That's because templates members aren't instantiated unless you use them. You don't have valid indexes for your element type.

Your indexes are trying the equivalent of

```
KeyValue pair;
unsigned Key::(*pfoo)() = &Key::foo;

pair.*pfoo
```

Instead of

```
pair.first.*pfoo;
```

You need accessors for `KeyValue`, not `Key`

```
unsigned int getFoo(const KeyValue & pair) {
    return pair.first.foo();
}
unsigned int getBar(const KeyValue & pair) {
    return pair.first.bar();
}
unsigned int getBaz(const KeyValue & pair) {
    return pair.first.baz();
}

using MyContainer = boost::multi_index_container<
    KeyValue,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<KeyValueTag>,
            boost::multi_index::composite_key<
                KeyValue,
                boost::multi_index::global_fun<KeyValue, unsigned int, &getFoo>,
                boost::multi_index::global_fun<KeyValue, unsigned int, &getBar>,
                boost::multi_index::global_fun<KeyValue, unsigned int, &getBaz>,
            >
        >,
        boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<BazTag>,
            boost::multi_index::global_fun<KeyValue, unsigned int, &getBaz>
        >,
        boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<BarTag>,
            boost::multi_index::global_fun<KeyValue, unsigned int, &getBar>
        >
    >
>;
```

Aside: If you have C++17 and boost 1.69 or later, you can use a much terser syntax for keys:

```
boost::multi_index::key<&getFoo, &getBar, &getBaz>
boost::multi_index::key<&getBar>
```

Comment: Excellent stuff. I'd personally add that using `mutable_pair` as the value type is probably a-typical and only used when people want to mimic std::map/std::unordered_map more closely. I consider that a strictly worse interface

Comment: @sehe it would be the same problem with `std::pair`. I could see having a `template <class Key, class Value, class UniqueIndex, class... OtherIndexes> using indexed_map = ...` that would use that

Comment: I meant, using any pair at all is a anathema here. It's a mer side-note in case OP doesn't realize that. I did start with noting that excellence of the answer :) I just don't think the library shines when you try  to emulate standard associative containers. Compare http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f1057710b2cab22

Comment: Amazing, this works! Just one thing @Caleth, it should be `KeyValue` not `KeyValue::first_type` on `global_fun` as the type

Comment: @Santiago oops, yes. I'm now so used to the terse syntax that I forgot to change those